# uvloop asks for python 3.7 but can be run with lower version

Tags: python, uvloop

I am using an open-source python package 'farm-Haystack' in my school project. When I installed the `requirements.txt` in python3.6 venv I got this error :

```
Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-t35n0vdx/uvloop_059c5c705acc434ab0515b073c3e079b/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError('uvloop requires Python 3.7 or greater')
    RuntimeError: uvloop requires Python 3.7 or greater
    ----------------------------------------
```

It's apparently saying that python 3.7 is needed for this package while I am using python 3.6. I didn't notice this error message at the time and keep working with the program. The program is compiled successfully and run as expected.

When I scrolled back and found the message I am really curious why this dependency can still be resolved. I can find `uvloop` via `pip freeze` and can also import it into my program. I am wondering what could be the possible result if `uvloop` does not match the python version it require, as I am totally unfamiliar with this package.

(I hope I don't have to upgrade the python version, it took me a long time to make everything run successfully)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like one of the packages includes an unpinned dependency for [uvloop](https://pypi.org/project/uvloop/).

Starting from [uvloop 0.15.0](https://pypi.org/project/uvloop/0.15.0/) it requires Python 3.7 or greater.

To fix it need to freeze the version in [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files):

```
...
uvloop==0.14.0
...
```